# Correcting Thiessen Polygons output from ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, intersection, voronoi-thiessen, environment-variable

I am try to divide irregularly shaped polygons at specific points. I don't have any fields that inform the angle at which the polygons should be divided. Based on the [Split polygon based on point feature](https://community.esri.com/t5/geoprocessing-questions/split-polygon-based-on-point-feature/m-p/352694) at GeoNet, I am trying the Thiessen Polygons + Intersect approach, and it's almost working.

In the screenshot below, the orange is my "irregularly shaped polygon" and blue at the Thiessen Polygons created from the green points.

[image]

Below has a general sketch of my desired outcome, the gray polygons, just sketched in PowerPoint.

Is there a way to make the Thiessen Polygons more like the gray polygons than the blue polygons?

Ultimately I am interested in the interseciton of the orange polygons and gray polygons.

[image]

I am using ArcMap 10.7 with an Advanced level license.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output extent is controlled by the `arcpy.env.extent` environment setting:  https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/environment-settings/output-extent.htm

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [comment](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/388044/115)/[answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/388081/115) by @mikewatt, this is the code that works:

```
import arcpy

#mypoly = filepath to my polygon SHP
#mypts = filepath to my points SHP
#myoutput = filepath to save Thiessen polgons output

arcpy.env.extent = mypoly
arcpy.CreateThiessenPolygons_analysis(mypts, myoutput, fields_to_copy='ALL')
```

[image]